# Twitter Boostrap Popover.js with farbtastic color picker content looses events attached

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker, popover

I'm using the bootsrap from twitter, and it's cool. Yet, I have a little problem. I'm trying to use the Popover plugin to generate on the fly color pickers related to each input with class .colorInput

Here's the code I came up with :

```
$('.colorInput').each(function()
{
    var src = $(this);

    src.popover({
        html:   true,
        trigger:    'manual',
        content:    function(){
            return $('<div/>').farbtastic(src);
        }
    }).focus(function(e){

        src.data('data-default', src.val());

        $('.colorInput').each(function(){
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });
        src.popover('show');


    }).blur(function(e){
        if(src.data('data-default') != src.val())
        {
            formSubmit();
        }

        src.popover('hide');
    });   
});
```

It's all working pretty well, except for one HUGE detail : when I set the popover's content via

```
return $('<div/>').farbtastic(src);
```

the returned data gets striped with any of the eventHandlers attached by the farbtastic plugin.
Any idea how I could keep the code as simple as it is, and NOt loose any of the events attached to the returned  ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with these plugins/libraries but I would suggest the following:

Change

```
 content:    function(){
    return $('<div/>').farbtastic(src);
 }
```

to

```
 content:    function(){
    return $('<div id="placeholder" />');
 }
```

and attach the `farbtastic` just before calling `show`:

```
.focus(function(e){

    src.data('data-default', src.val());

    $('.colorInput').each(function(){
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });

    $('<div id="placeholder" />').farbtastic(src);
    src.popover('show');
}
```